# How to build multiplayer games for android?

Tags: android, multiplayer, databases, online

I'd like to know how to build android multiplayer games but I'm struggling to find a step-by-step or good resources on this topic. My main questions is which engine and api to use? I'd like to achieve this with the technologies I already know such as Firebase and Libgdx on android studio.

All my researches point to things like Unity, Godot and unreal. Is this the only/better way to go since I want to build simple games such as [pool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miniclip.eightballpool) ?

What I want to build is a multiplayer game on where the users should be able to invite friend from their social media to play against, provide rankings and sharing results on social media. ONLY for Android, using Java and free resources (APIs, db's, engines).

A good example would be [Trivia Crack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.etermax.preguntados.lite&hl=en_usa) how is this game (probably) made? which technologies?

Comment: `simple` and `multiplayer` do not go together. Have you got experience making any game? A tutorial about making a multiplayer game from scratch will have 500 steps, but a tutorial about adding multiplayer functionality to an already existing game will be 50 steps, if that makes sense.

Comment: It's unlikely you get an out-of-the-box solution to your problem. There are many ideas to consider and to plan your path (server-based, dynamic binding via bluetooth or similar, synchron, asynchron, .. ...) There is literature out there to learn more about it. Blunt speaking - it will take you some weeks to months (depending on your learning speed) to get into this materia and build some multiplayer-environments. And your first tries will not be stable (lagg, disconnects, weak connections, data-loss, ..)

It took us about a year to get a stable system which a nice uptime. Good luck.